# Xamarin custom font using xml

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.android

I currently am making an android application using Xamarin NATIVE, not forms. I'm having issues getting the fonts to work properly. I've tried following this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/fonts) it doesn't appear to be complete.

I've been using an extension, XamarIDEA to do most of the UI work in Android Studio since for whatever reason, I'm unable to load the .axml designer in visual studio in a stable fashion. My goal is to be able to reference a font file (.otf format) . I put my .otf files inside `/ProjectRoot/Resources/font`. I've then made a font.xml file in the same directory as these fonts (/ProjectRoot/Resources/font) inside this font.xml file, I have the following xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<font android:font="@font/mindburger_studio_bambino_new_bold"
      android:fontStyle="normal"
      android:fontWeight="700"
      app:font="@font/mindburger_studio_bambino_new_bold"
      app:fontStyle="normal"
      app:fontWeight="700"  />


</font-family>
```

I can't reference this font in my TextView as such. The font just simply isn't applied.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/mindburger_studio_bambino_new"
    android:text="@string/todays_price"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
    tools:text="@string/todays_price" />
```

Has anyone been successful in using custom fonts in a xamarin native app using xml as the display? I know it's doable via code, but doing so for so many controls via code seems hacky.